# Radical of prime ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $I$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Show that $\sqrt{I}$ is a prime ideal.

My attempt: Let $ab\in\sqrt{I}$. Then $(ab)^m\in I$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ by the definition of radical ideal.

Since $I$ is prime, and $R$ is commutative, we have $a\in I$ or $a^{m-1}b^m\in I$.

And also we have $I\subset \sqrt{I}$, so $a\in \sqrt{I}$ or $a^{m-1}b^m\in\sqrt{I}$.

Since $m$ is a finite number, we can repeat this process until we get $a\in \sqrt{I}$ or $b\in\sqrt{I}$.

I'm not quite sure this repeating process is acceptable or not. Is this a correct proof? And, is there another way to prove it?

Comment: Your proof is correct, but you’re missing an essential observation.

Comment: @k.stm What is it?

Comment: @user642721 I guess the author of this problem just wanted you to verify that $\sqrt{I}$ is prime directly as you have. But soon one should learn that $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of prime ideals containing $I$. If $I$ is prime, that implies $I=\sqrt{I}$.  See if you can piece all that together.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, what you *really* should be proving is something stronger. Here are two ways to think about this:

- What happens if you apply your reasoning to any $x ∈ \sqrt I$, not just to products $x = ab$?
- You can characterize both being prime and being radical in terms of factor rings: For ideals $I, J ⊆ R$,
  \begin{align*}
  I ⊆ R ~\text{prime} &\iff R/I~\text{domain} \\
  J ⊆ R ~\text{radical} &\iff R/J~…
  \end{align*}

Comment: $x\in\sqrt{I}\implies x^m\in I\implies x\in \sqrt{I}$ or $x^{m-1}\in\sqrt{I}$... this doesn't seem to take us to nowhere. And $R/J$ maybe stronger one? Like field? But I think it's for the maximal ideal?

Comment: @user642721 No, not a field, but something *weaker* than a domain: The notion I was hinting at is that of a [reduced ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring). Your conclusion is not quite right. If $I$ is a prime ideal, then $x^m ∈ I \implies x ∈ I~\text{or}~x^{m-1} ∈ I$ – where does this lead?